# Sum up to n terms of a series containing binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to find the expected value of a random variable which results in the following summation:
$$
\frac{1}{n^{2n}} \sum_{r=1}^n r \binom{n}{r} (n-r)^{2n}
$$
Can someone please help me solve it

Thanks in advance!!

P.S.: I am new on here and this is my first question.. please forgive for any mistakes made in asking questions or any other associated thing

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I have also edited your post for clarity. Please check that it matches your intent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if a closed form is possible but it is possible to get a good approximation as follows. First, we use the following identity which can be proved using the binomial theorem and taking derivatives.

$$
\sum_{r=1}^n rx^r \binom{n}r = nx(x+1)^{n-1}.
$$

For an upper bound, note that your quantity can be written as
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r \binom{n}r \left( 1 - \frac{r}n \right)^{2n} \le \sum_{r=1}^n r \binom{n}r e^{-2r} = ne^{-2}(1+e^{-2})^{n-1} = O(1.14^n) $$
where we have used the estimate $1-x \le e^{-x}$ and the above identity.

A lower bound can be proved similarly. Note that $1-x \ge e^{-1.4x}$ for $x \le 0.5$. Hence, we can say that your quantity is at least
$$ ne^{-2.8}(1+e^{-2.8})^{n-1}  = O(1.06^n)$$
minus an error term that is of the order 
$$ \binom{n}{n/2} \frac{1}{4^n} = O(.5^n) $$
so it is negligible.